# Where is the ActionPack Gemspec file in rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3685-actionpack-235-gem-declares-incompatibility-with-rack-110

I am attempting to get thin running with rails 2.3.5 and it seems I need to modify some of the source code.  Unfortunately I can't seem to locate this actionpack-2.3.5.gemspec.  It is in the directory for rails 3 but for 2.3.5 I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

The Lighthouse ticket that you linked to mentions that it's embedded within the Rakefile: http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/Rakefile

```
spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.name = PKG_NAME
  s.version = PKG_VERSION
  s.summary = "Web-flow and rendering framework putting the VC in MVC."
  s.description = %q{Eases web-request routing, handling, and response as a half-way front, half-way page controller. Implemented with specific emphasis on enabling easy unit/integration testing that doesn't require a browser.} #'

  s.author = "David Heinemeier Hansson"
  s.email = "david@loudthinking.com"
  s.rubyforge_project = "actionpack"
  s.homepage = "http://www.rubyonrails.org"

  s.has_rdoc = true
  s.requirements << 'none'

  s.add_dependency('activesupport', '= 2.3.6' + PKG_BUILD)
  s.add_dependency('rack', '~> 1.0.0')

  s.require_path = 'lib'
  s.autorequire = 'action_controller'

  s.files = [ "Rakefile", "install.rb", "README", "RUNNING_UNIT_TESTS", "CHANGELOG", "MIT-LICENSE" ]
  dist_dirs.each do |dir|
    s.files = s.files + Dir.glob( "#{dir}/**/*" ).delete_if { |item| item.include?( "\.svn" ) }
  end
end
```